# euler project #10 cannot get the answer on java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum=0;

    problemTen a= new problemTen();
    for (int i=2; i<2000000 ; i++){
        if(a.isPrime(i))
            sum += i;

    }
    System.out.println(sum);



}

public boolean isPrime(long num){
    if(num==1) return false;
    if(num==2) return true;
    for (int k=2; k<num; k++){
        if(num%k ==0) return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Console is not giving me any answers. Can you please hand ?

Comment: Did you check to see if your loop is still executing?

Comment: I think it is because it doesn't stop the running time . Don't know how to handle

Comment: People who haven't heard of the sieve of Eratosthenes make me sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to just run slowly. You can improve its performance in few ways:

- you don't need to test for `1` or `2` in your `isPrime(long num)` method since you already started looping from `2` and you are already testing this value with `for (int k=2; k<num; k++){`
- don't test all numbers, but only odd ones (you already know that `4`, `6`, ... are not prime) so instead of

  ```
  for (int i=2; i<2000000 ; i++)
  ```

  you can use

  ```
  for (int i=3; i<2000000 ; i+=2)
  //         ^              ^^^^ - changes
  ```

  but don't forget to initialize `sum` with `2` instead of `0`.
- but biggest impact on performance is avoiding testing values above `sqrt(num)` value in `isPrime`. Think of it, if some number is not prime, it means that it can be written as `number = x * y`. Assuming that `x`<=`y` we know that `x`<=`sqrt(number)`<=`y` so if we warn't able to find `x` there is no point in searching for `y`. So in `isPrime` instead of

  ```
  for (int k=2; k<num; k++)
  ```

  use

  ```
  int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(num);  
  for (int k = 2; k <= sqrt; k++)
  //              ^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  So for `num` like `123454321` max number of iterations wouldn't be `~123454321` but `sqrt(123454321) = 11111`